# Accessing three different variables form one file in three different functions in C++

Tags: c++, function, variables, ifstream

I am really new in C++.
      I have a file containing three columns of data e.g.
      a1 a2 a3.
      Now I want to ifstream the value of a1, a2, and a3 in three different functions. like

```
    ifstream input("file.txt"); 
    input >> a1;
    input >> a2;
    input >> a3;
   int Function1()
                {
                 Here I want to access a1
                }

   int Function2()
                {
                Here I want to access a2
                }
   int Function3()
                {
                Here I want to access a3
               }
```

How can I do that?
Looking for kind help.

Comment: Just pass them as parameters to each function.

Comment: you can also make the a1, a2, a3 static.

Comment: @Mohit what do you mean? `static` has so many meanings in C++ ...

Comment: @bolov As a global static variables in CPP file.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. As it stands the code doesnt make much sense and some guessing is needed to turn it into something that can be compiled

Comment: @Mohit aha. I see. Well, global variables should be avoided. And especially for somebody who is just learning we should not teach them to use global variables instead of function arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass them as parameters.
For example:

```
int Function1(int x) { return x + 1; }
int Function2(int x) { return x + 2; }
int Function3(int x) { return x + 3; }

// ...

int a1 = 0;
int a2 = 0;
int a3 = 0;
ifstream input("file.txt"); 
if (input >> a1 >> a2 >> a3)
{
    cout << Function1(a1) + Function2(a2) - Function3(a3);
}
```

Comment: Hi all,  Thank you very much ...it works now.